# How to detect a call made using openUrl() is ended in ios

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, call, openurl

In my application, there is an option to make a call when the user taps a phone number. I'm implementing this as shown below:

```
if let url = URL(string:"tel://\(String(describing: Util.checkForNullString(contactNo)))"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url){
    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
}
```

I want to do another action soon after the user finishes the call. But how to get notified when the call is finished ?

Comment: I think *you can't*. Once the call is finished, the user returns to the phone app and you have no callback or notification whatsoever (please anyone can confirm this).

Comment: What do you mean by "call ... is ended"?

Comment: Your app will be put in the background once the Phone app is launched. The user may not ever return to your app. Your app could be terminated while in the background. The user may use your app while on the phone call. The user may use other apps while on the phone call.

Comment: One suggestion is that you can use telprompt:// instead of tel://. When you use telprompt, once the call is completed the app will be launched. After the app is launched you can handle the scenarios that you want.

Comment: Ok. I will try with telprompt. Thanks.